# Adding Gradient to the navigation bar will hide bar buttons items in iOS 13.0 +

Tags: ios, swift, layer, navigationbar

I added a Gradient layer to my navigation bar and also having bar button item , just in iOS 13.0 + when I used this gradient layer my bar button items will hide and when I swipe the view to back to the previous page I will see them but when its full screen I can not see them although I can see them in old iOS versions without any problem and also in UI Debugging

```
extension UIImage {
static func getGradientImage(withColors colors: [UIColor], view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: colors)
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    return UIImage.image(from: gradient) ?? UIImage()
}

 static func image(from layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size,
                                           layer.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 }
}
```

so this one was set navigation gradient layer background and also after this

```
  if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        if let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage.getGradientImage(withColors: [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9258083701, green: 0.4127946496, blue: 0, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.7787303329, green: 0.01916297711, blue: 0.1483061314, alpha: 1)], view: navBar)
        }
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
    } else {}
    
    
    self.navigationBackButtonTitle(str.back)
    let topTitle = UIBarButtonItem()
    topTitle.title = "Top Title"
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = topTitle
```

so what the problem can be ?

Comment: layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)

Comment: I tested that it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Best practice of gradient navigation bar is setting gradient background image for iOS 13. Adding through layer will cause the problem you ask.

Basically first you need to create gradient image from the colors.

```
    static func getGradientImage(withColors colors: [UIColor], view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer(colors: colors)
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    return UIImage.image(from: gradient) ?? UIImage()
}

static func image(from layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size,
                                           layer.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

After that you need to set navigation bar background image with navigation bar appearance.

```
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        if let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage.getGradientImage(withColors: colors, view: navBar)
        }
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: this made the navigation bar clear not with gradient color but I think this is the correct way but I have to change these codes to be working

Comment: Where did you set the navigation bar appearance it can be in `didFinishLaunching` in options if you are using across the all app or if you are using only single viewcontroller you can set it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: Interesting, can you share the code block of that you write down. Because I'm using exact same usage on my apps and it's working.Also can you put a break point inside the`if let navBar` check to ensure the function called?. @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: Can you ensure that with putting breakpoint to the if let navBar code block is called or not? @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: yes it's called all of them called the navigation background color is red only

Comment: I even call the function in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but still doesn't work